# GCM Registration with http rest api

Tags: api, rest, google-cloud-messaging

In order to implement the GCM on a app (developed by service.appinventor) I'm looking up a workaround to use HTTP REST API. 
Unfortunately, by documentation https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#automatic-retry-using-exponential-back-off
seems that I can only use Istance ID API.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by workaround to use Rest API? Try this forum [Google Cloud Messaging ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mitappinventortest/kW6uJ6T0koY) to find some implementation and documentation, see Raoul and Toston Apps post. Some just follow the [Set up a GCM Client App on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client).

Comment: thanks for your answer. Appinventor2 hasn't GCM capability, also because it doesn't work in background. services.appinventor is a appinventor2 with background capability, but there isn't gcm implemented yet. My question was addressed to know if the GCM registration could be implemented by Rest API. For example we can implement Auth 2.0 by rest api too. If we can do the same also with GCM so I think we can add this capability to services,appinventor too.

Answer (score 0):

Has someone a suggestion?
I need a workaround to implement GCM registration (described here https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation) using REST API.